# How to fix 'google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message' while running optimize_for_inference.py

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I am retraining `mobilenet_v1_1.0_224` on my custom dataset. I have generated the required `graph.pb` file and want to run the model in an android app. Tried to run `optimize_for_inference.py` to generate an optimized file but got an error saying - `google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message`

I checked for `protobuf` installation and it is present. I am running the following -

```
!python tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py \
--input = model_output/graph_v1.pb \
--output = model_output/optimized_graph_v1.pb \
--input_names = input \
--output_names = MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py", line 165, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py", line 83, in main
    input_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Am using tensorflow version 1.4.0

Answer (score 2):

I removed the spaces before and after '=' while passing values to the arguments. Now it works fine